# I Am Within, I Am Without. Sometimes Off, Sometimes On

Tags: riddle

> To some readers, I bring happiness
>
> To some players, I bring sadness
>
> Most of you like me as long as I am good
>
> I hang out with Mark, in the rain with a coat
>
> I can be a point, two lines or a rectangle
>
> Sometimes a cross but never a triangle
>
> I mix in the background, with a body, with a sound
>
> I am within, I am without, sometimes off, sometimes on

Who am I?

Hint

A five letter word which is both noun and verb

Comment: Not an affix riddle for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New answer!

> You are a check.

To some readers, I bring happiness

> When people see the checkmark on a test it brings happiness.

To some players, I bring sadness

> In chess... check is where the king is threatened. Checkmate is a loss.

Most of you like me as long as I am good

> A good check where the latter means investigation is liked.

I hang out with Mark, in the rain with a coat

> The first half is referring to a Checkmark and second, rain check and check coat.

I can be a point, two lines or a rectangle

> Checkpoint, the checkmark symbol or the check tile.

Sometimes a cross but never a triangle

> Reference to cross check, triangle-check does not exist.

I mix in the background, with a body, with a sound

> Clue for the phrases background check or maybe the check pattern, body check and soundcheck.

I am within, I am without, sometimes off, sometimes on

> A reference to the phrases: in check/check in, check out, check off and check on.

> Check has five letters and is both a noun and a verb!

Comment: While your answer fits a number of clues for others it is quite a stretch.vs svfg vf n erpgnatyr ( n erny fgergpu), bar pna rnfvyl perngr n Gevnatyr jvgu svatref. Jung nobhg enva?  Nyfb unaqf naq pbng vf n fgergpu gbb . Although it is interesting how your answer fits so many other clues. Thanks

Comment: New answer!!!!!

Comment: Yeh!  Good Logical Thinking there

Answer (score 0):

Is it:

> Book

To some readers, I bring happiness

> A lot of people enjoy reading books

To some players, I bring sadness

> To book can mean to foul someone in certain sports

Most of you like me as long as I am good

> A lot of people like a 'good book'

I hang out with Mark

> Book*mark*

I only got clues for a couple of lines

Comment: In the rain? With the coat?  Please re think.

Comment: Yes, it was only an initial reaction

Comment: I think your "connection" logic is the way to go.

Answer (score -2):

is it . . .

> light

To some readers, I bring happiness

> Enough light for reading

I am within, I am without, sometimes off, sometimes on

> it can be off or ON

I hang out with Mark, in the rain with a coat

> rainbow

I can be a point, two lines or a rectangle

> Tube lights , incandescent light